# where to set the accessibility properties of nscontrol in xcode 6 interface builder

Tags: xcode, accessibility

in earlier version of  xcode interface builder, there is a accessibility section under the identity inspector where could select the accessibility property of a nscontrol like button, table, etc. However I can not find the section in xcode 6, any one know where to find it?

Thanks